# Unable to remove empty keys in a python list

Tags: python

I have a python list like this

```
payload = [
    {
        "id": 123456,
        "name": 'CrissCross',
        "color": 'blue',
        "sales date": '2020-06-06',
        "vendor_vl": 143,
        "vendor_tx": 97
    },
    {
        "id":123456,
        "name": 'CrissCross',
        "color": 'blue',
        "sales date": '2020-06-06',
        "height": 188,
        "Weight": 92
    },
    {
        "id": 123456 ,
        "name": 'CrissCross',
        "color": 'blue',
        "sales date": '2020-06-06',
        "actual_vl": ""
    }
]
```

and I want to remove empty keys when I receive some null value
In my exemple, I need to remove all third block

```
    {
        "id": 123456 ,
        "name": 'CrissCross',
        "color": 'blue',
        "sales date": '2020-06-06',
        "actual_vl": ""
    }
```

... because the "actual_vl": ""

This is my code and it's only removing "actual_vl": "", but I need to remove third block

this is my code

```
payload = {k:v for (k,v) in payload.items() if v != ""}
print(payload)
```

but as result I keep getting all fiels.

Comment: `v` is the entire dictionary. You need another level of iteration.

Comment: Your code should get an error. `payload` is a list, not a dictionary.

Comment: So you have a list of dictionaries and in case if some dictionary has empty key you want to remove it completely from the list, right?

Comment: Yes @MonsieurMerso this is a list. in case the last field is empty, it is to remove the header plus the field.
In my example, I need to remove the entire block bellow
`{
    "id": 123456 ,
    "name": 'CrissCross',
    "color": 'blue',
    "sales date": '2020-06-06',
    "actual_vl": ""
}`
Just because the "actual_vl": "" has no value

Answer (score 4):

`payload` is the list, it doesn't have an `items()` method. Use a list comprehension for that.

Then you can use `values()` to get all the values and test if any of them are empty.

```
payload = [d for d in payload if "" not in d.values())
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the all() function on dictionary values to determine if all keys have a non-empty value:

```
payload = [d for d in payload if all(d.values())]
```

...

```
print(payload)

[{'id': 123456, 'name': 'CrissCross', 'color': 'blue', 
  'sales date': '2020-06-06', 'vendor_vl': 143, 'vendor_tx': 97}, 
 {'id': 123456, 'name': 'CrissCross', 'color': 'blue', 
  'sales date': '2020-06-06', 'height': 188, 'Weight': 92}]
```

*Note that this will treat 0 and False as empty (which may or may not be what you want)*

Answer (score 0):

You could use `filter`:

```
list(filter(lambda x: all(len(str(y)) != 0 for y in x.values()), payload))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[{'id': 123456, 'name': 'CrissCross', 'color': 'blue', 'sales date': '2020-06-06', 'vendor_vl': 143, 'vendor_tx': 97}, {'id': 123456, 'name': 'CrissCross', 'color': 'blue', 'sales date': '2020-06-06', 'height': 188, 'Weight': 92}]
```